# No notification sound through Android device using GCM service

Tags: android, mono, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am delivering notifications through the GCM service to android devices. Delivering messages to client is not a problem its the fact that no sound is played when the notification is received on the phone which is the issue.

I am using the following code on the client side (mono android) to build up notification request

```
void createNotification(string title, string desc)
     {
       //Create notification
       var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

    //Create an intent to show ui
    var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Main));

    //Create the notification
    var notification = new Notification(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail, title);

    //Auto cancel will remove the notification once the user touches it
    notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

    //Set the notification info
    //we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
    //when the notification is tapped.
    notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, title, desc, PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0));

    //Show the notification
    notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
}
```

Where in here can I place details of notification sound to play?  I have tried the Notification.Sound member but it asks for a uri which I dont have a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

Add this if you want to play custom notification sound

```
  notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line of code in function activated default notification sound.

```
notification.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;
```